# Как получить url с помощью jQuery через консоль браузера?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, javascript

***Как получить url с помощью jQuery через консоль браузера?***

Не делал такого раньше, не знаю  даже, где поискать инфу по этому вопросу. Может, подскажите, как это сделать или что почитать?

Comment: url чего именно?

Comment: @Shadow33, По возможности публикуйте ответы на форуме, они могут помочь многим в будущем.

Comment: @Shadow33, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(location).prop('href');` и не благодарите.

Answer (score 2):

[location.href](http://javascript.ru/window-location)